# How to run .sh and get return value from Java with file association on Windows

Tags: java, windows, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-association

#### Background

I am writing a Java program that runs a `.sh` file specified in `.properties` files and get its return value. The path of `.sh` file is specified from `.properties` files like:

```
command=C:/tmp/hoge.sh
args[0]=foo
args[1]=bar
args[2]=baz
```

And the Java program reads it like:

```java
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("resources/command.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(is);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(prop.getProperty("command"));
list.add(prop.getProperty("args[0]"));
list.add(prop.getProperty("args[1]"));
list.add(prop.getProperty("args[2]"));

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
Process p = pb.start();
int returnValue = p.exitValue();
```

This program runs on Linux in the production environment. But due to development environment management, we are using Windows as a development environment.

#### Prerequisites

- There are so many `.sh` and `.properties` files on our system. So I want to use the same `.properties` files on the development environment and the production environment, or at least I want to use the `.properties` files with simple string replacement (on the example above, what I have to do is just replace the `command=C:` to `command=`). I want to avoid to prepare the dedicated `.properties` files for the development environment and the production environment separately.
- We are using the Windows version of Java mainly due to two reasons: 1) The middleware we call from Java program (it only supports Windows and RHEL, but doesn't support WSL environment), and 2) The skillset of project members (there are only a few members who can use both of Windows and Linux fluently).
- We want to avoid the additional code that is used only in the development environment as much as possible, because of the code coverage measurement and the quality management.

#### What I have tried and confirmed

To test the Java program and `.sh` file in the Windows environment, I have decided to use WSL2.

To run `.sh` on Windows, I have set up WSL2 and modified file association for `.sh` files. I have added following default value to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\sh_auto_file\shell\open\command` to run `.sh` on WSL2:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "$arg=\"%1\";wsl (\"/mnt/\"+[System.Char]::ToLower($arg[0])+$arg.Substring(2,$arg.Length-2) -replace '\\', '/'); exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

On the command prompt, I have confirmed that I can run `.sh` with Bash on WSL2 via the file association and get the return value of `.sh` properly.

```
C:\tmp>hoge.sh

C:\tmp>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
5
```

The content of `hoge.sh` is:

```sh
sleep 1
exit 5
```

#### Problem

The Java program runs `.sh` file properly on Linux. But on Windows, it causes an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/tmp/hoge.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more
```

#### Question

How can I run `.sh` from Java with file association on WSL2? Or, is there no way to launch programs according to file association and get the return value in Java?

Note that you can launch programs with the file association via `java.awt.Desktop#open()`, but it doesn't have a method to get the return value.

Note also that preparing a `.properties` file for the development environment like below needs very hard work on our prerequisites.

```
command=wsl
args[0]=C:/tmp/hoge.sh
args[1]=foo
args[2]=bar
args[3]=baz
```

Comment: Apologies if I missed this detail in the question, but is there a reason you need to run the *Windows* version of Java in this case?  I understand that your development environment is Windows, but can you install and run the Linux version of Java under WSL?  Or does this (I'm guessing) break your debug or build workflow under your Windows development environment?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds We are using the Windows version of Java mainly due to two reasons: 1) The middleware we call from Java program (it only supports Windows and RHEL, but doesn't support WSL environment), and 2) The skillset of project members (there are only a few members who can use Windows and Linux fluently). I have added detail to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make both Windows and Linux versions run BASH -c "yourcommand" to simplify the differences in OS handling. WSL installs BASH.EXE, confirm it is there with CMD.EXE:

```
> where bash
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
```

If your PATH is set correctly on both OS you can just use "bash" as the command:

```
String [] cmd = new String[] { "bash" , "-c", "Insert command 'args[0]' 'args[1]' ... here"};
```

For the above to work though you'd need to construct `cmd[2]` as one string containing the args[0..N] values separated by space AND escaped with quotes if they also contained spaces so that the correct parameters are given to your script. Something like:

```
cmd[2] = prop.getProperty("command")+" "+ prop.getProperty("arg[0]") ...
```

If your Path is not setup you can adjust your launch code to pick `bash.exe` or `/bin/bash` based on `os.name`:

```
final String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
//final boolean IS_WINDOWS = OS.startsWith("windows");
final boolean IS_LINUX   = OS.startsWith("linux");

String bash = IS_LINUX ? "/bin/bash" : "bash.exe" ;  // May need full path shown by where bash.EXE
String [] cmd = new String[] { bash , "-c", "Insert command  args[0] args[1] ... here"};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to avoid the additional code that is used only in the development environment as much as possible. I have added the prerequisites to the question.

Comment: You need 2 versions of your properties file as one contains "C:" drive letter .If you get "bash" working on both OS there is no difference to the launching code, and anyway you can encode all the required differences needed in those properties config files so the code coverage is identical.